# RecylerView no es capaz de referenciar a los TextViews

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, cardview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que conecta a una base de datos y muestra los registros de cada tabla en un RecyclerView que dentro tiene CardViews, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación me aparece el siguiente mensaje en el compilador de Android Studio:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.clinicabd, PID: 2301
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
> null object reference
> at com.example.clinicabd.AdapterPaciente.onBindViewHolder(AdapterPaciente.java:57)
> at com.example.clinicabd.AdapterPaciente.onBindViewHolder(AdapterPaciente.java:18)

Regresando a la aplicación, en el archivo del adaptador del RecyclerView, que es a donde me referencian estas líneas de error, me aparece que los textviews no se relacionan correctamente en el proyecto porque son nulos, adjunto la codificación del adaptador:

public class AdapterPaciente extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPaciente.ViewHolder> {

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView name;
        private TextView direccion;
        private TextView telCasa;
        private TextView telMovil;
        private TextView nombreEmer;
        private TextView telEmer;
        private TextView observaciones;
        private TextView codigo;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
            direccion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDireccion);
            telCasa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTelCasa);
            telMovil = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTelMovil);
            nombreEmer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreEmer);
            telEmer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTelEmer);
            observaciones = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvObservar);
            codigo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCode);
        }
    }

    public List<elemento_paciente> listapaciente;

    public AdapterPaciente(List<elemento_paciente> items) {
        this.listapaciente = items;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterPaciente.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_paciente, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterPaciente.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getName());
        holder.direccion.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getDireccion());
        holder.telCasa.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getTelCasa());
        holder.telMovil.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getTelMovil());
        holder.nombreEmer.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getNombreEmer());
        holder.telEmer.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getTelEmer());
        holder.observaciones.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getObservaciones());
        holder.codigo.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getCodigo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return listapaciente.size();
    }
}
```

La línea 57 que me marca de error es la siguiente:

```
holder.name.setText(listapaciente.get(position).getName());
```

Y por consiguiente las líneas que le siguen donde se capturan los demás campos de la tabla tendrán el mismo error.

El archivo elemento_paciente.java, que es donde está inicializado el método getName() y los demás métodos, es el siguiente:

```
public class elemento_paciente {
    private String name;
    private String direccion;
    private int telCasa;
    private int telMovil;
    private String nombreEmer;
    private int telEmer;
    private String observaciones;
    private int codigo;

    public elemento_paciente() {

    }

    public elemento_paciente(String name, String direccion, int telCasa, int telMovil, String nombreEmer, int telEmer, String observaciones, int codigo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telCasa = telCasa;
        this.telMovil = telMovil;
        this.nombreEmer = nombreEmer;
        this.telEmer = telEmer;
        this.observaciones = observaciones;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public int getTelCasa() {
        return telCasa;
    }

    public void setTelCasa(int telCasa) {
        this.telCasa = telCasa;
    }

    public int getTelMovil() {
        return telMovil;
    }

    public void setTelMovil(int telMovil) {
        this.telMovil = telMovil;
    }

    public String getNombreEmer() {
        return nombreEmer;
    }

    public void setNombreEmer(String nombreEmer) {
        this.nombreEmer = nombreEmer;
    }

    public int getTelEmer() {
        return telEmer;
    }

    public void setTelEmer(int telEmer) {
        this.telEmer = telEmer;
    }

    public String getObservaciones() {
        return observaciones;
    }

    public void setObservaciones(String observaciones) {
        this.observaciones = observaciones;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

Por último el archivo pacientes.java es donde se conecta con la base de datos y se muestran los datos en el recyclerView, y se manda a llamar al adaptador.

```
public class pacientes extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvLista;
    private AdapterPaciente adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pacientes);

        rvLista = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvListaPacientes);
        rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        adapter=new AdapterPaciente(obtainPaciente());
        rvLista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public List<elemento_paciente> obtainPaciente(){
        ConexionBD cn=new ConexionBD();
        List<elemento_paciente> paciente= new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            Statement leerDatos=cn.Conectar().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=leerDatos.executeQuery("select * from Paciente");

            while(rs.next()){
                paciente.add(new elemento_paciente(rs.getString("nombre"), rs.getString("direccion"), rs.getInt("tel_casa"),
                        rs.getInt("tel_movil"), rs.getString("nombre_emergencia"), rs.getInt("tel_emergencia"), rs.getString("observaciones"),
                        rs.getInt("cod_paciente")));
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return paciente;
    }

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a lograr arreglar este asunto con el RecyclerView o si para mi caso es mejor usar un listview.

Answer (score 0):

Estás pudiendo obtener la referencia de los elementos mediante `findViewById()`, pero el problema es que los elementos que tratas de referenciar se encuentran en algún layout de tu proyecto, pero no en el que defines en `onCreateViewHolder()` que es `elemento_paciente.xml`, asegura que las vistas en realidad se encuentran en este layout.